# This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have already SQL Server Management Studio 2008R2 on my local machine.
I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and wanted to connect for the first time.
After going through the following steps

```
-> Open SSMS 2005
-> In Connect to SQL Server Dialogue
    -> Servername dropdown(select browse for servers)
    -> Select Network Servers tab
    -> Wait for some time the you will see the SSMS 2008 R2 instance
    -> Database Enginer tree view is expanded
    -> Selected the instance which is showing my computer's name and appended \SQLEXPRESS to it.
-> Selected windows Authentication mode
-> Hit connect button
```

Then I'm seeing a popup saying

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to User-Name\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionDlg)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

How to connect to SSMS 2005 without uninstalling SSMS 2008 R2?? 
Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want both SSMS 2005 and SSMS Express 2008 R2? If you want Management Studio Express you should get the most recent version, not the 2005 version. And you aren't going to have much luck using both the full version of SSMS and the Express version.

Comment: Just wanted to see whether I'll be getting Copy Database option. You said that execute script in target empty db but on the hosting server why I don't know but I was unable to execute scripts. But it is allowing me to copy, export, create tables.

Comment: The Copy Database option is missing because it's not supported against Express. It has nothing to do with trying 15 different versions of Management Studio. You could have backed up the database in 30 seconds, why not just do that?

Comment: @windson I assume this is something that you're hoping will provide a workaround for the problem presented in the answer [to your other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/copy-database-option-not-found-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2). Unfortunately the issue lies with the *server* and not the tooling. You'd have to "downgrade" your SQL Server Express version to even attempt this. Given the LOE on that task, why not follow Aaron's advice and backup/restore??

Comment: How can I do that? I presume that I will be as follows:
Take back up of db .bak which is on local hard drive (as in my case).
Next go to the hosted db select restore option and search for .bak on hard drive.
Is that the process. I saying with general common sense. If I'm wrong please correct me. Thanks

Comment: So your host does not provide you a way to supply a .bak file other than on their local hard drive? I'm sure there is a way to FTP the file. And if not, then you also got another suggestion: generate a script for the database ("Generate Scripts" is on that very same context menu). This should be especially easy since you've already stated the database is empty. You generate the script on your local database, then you copy and paste it into a query window for the hosted database. Hit F5, voila, you're done! No installing 15 versions of Management Studio trying to work around the "problem."

Answer (score 9):

### Presenting Symptom

You're attempting to connect to a database server (SQL Server 2008 R2) with a previous version's tooling (SQL Server 2005). Unfortunately, SSMS is not particularly forward compatible in this case. The answer to this problem is to install the correct tooling for the product that you're actually using (SSMS for 2008 R2).

### Solution to the Presenting Symptom

Use SSMS appropriate for SQL Server 2008 R2.

### Actual Problem

Having said that, it appears as though you're attempting a workaround to your [initial question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/copy-database-option-not-found-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2) which has a [perfectly satisfactory answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19720/4490) even though it doesn't get what you want because it is a feature of a SQL **Server** version that you do not have installed - not the client tools.

### Solution to the Actual Problem

Spend less time trying to work around versions in an attempt to use GUI tasks, and follow the advice of the well-known, well-respected users who've attempted to help, through either:

1. [Generating](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/copy-database-option-not-found-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2#comment31596_19719) the [database scripts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/copy-database-option-not-found-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2#comment31599_19719) since it is reported to be an empty database
2. [Backing up and restoring the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19733/this-version-of-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-express-can-only-be-used#comment31637_19733) ([`WITH MOVE`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CH8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms190447(v%3Dsql.105).aspx&ei=1ZXkT4mACoTJ6gHMz5ChCg&usg=AFQjCNFdxlqC_d8akpD_vRDIhjE5yy1cTg&sig2=puWSepXGD9E_uczs_iQwEg), of course if it's going to a different location)